# Processes die when pexpect session ends

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pexpect

I am using pexpect to run a start command on an in-house application. The start command starts a number of processes. As the processes are starting one by one in the background everything looks good, but when the 'start' process finishes and the pexpect process ends, the processes that have been started also die.

```
child = pexpect.spawn('foo start')
child.logfile = log
child.wait()
```

For this scenario, I can use nohup and it works as expected.

```
child = pexpect.spawn('bash -c "nohup foo start"')
```

However, there is also an installer for the same in-house application that has the same issue, part of the installation is to start the processes. The installer is interactive and requires input, so nohup will not work.

How can I prevent the processes that are started by the installer from dying when the pexpect session ends?

Note: The start and install processes work fine when executed from a standard terminal session. They are not tied to the session in any way.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find much in the documentation about it, but including the "ignore_sighup=True" option in the spawn command fixed my issue.

```
child = pexpect.spawn('foo start', ignore_sighup=True)
```